# utf8_general_ci causes broken characters

Tags: php, utf-8, decode, encode

```
$sql = "SELECT bdId, bdTitle FROM board"; 
$result = dbQuery($sql);    
            for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
            {   
                $row = dbFetchAssoc($result);
                $newsId = $row['bdId'];
                echo '<li><a href="index.php?view=detailedNews&newsId=' . '$newsId">' .$row['bdTitle'] . '</li>';
            }
```

I'm trying to echo non-english text from 'bdTitle' column which is stored as utf8_general_ci.  However, that codes gives me bunch of questions marks  like ' ????? . ????.?????? '  What's the problem here and how can I print the texts properly?

Comment: FYI, `utf8_general_ci` is the *collation* setting. This is not the same and actually has nothing to do with the *encoding* the string is stored in. Collations only influence how text is sorted and compared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set utf-8 encoding for your database connection

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass'); 

mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
```

Comment: Thank you. I used '$dbConn->set_charset("utf8");' and everything magically worked!

Comment: set_charset does the same. :)